# FL Studio 20 on Ubuntu Studio Won't Run

Tags: wine, playonlinux, ubuntu-studio

been trying to get FL Studio to run on Ubuntu Studio 20.10 for the past two days now. I've tried downloading wine and it installs fine, but upon launching the application I receive an error that follows.

```
FL Studio (20.8.0.2115) has encountered an error and needs to restart.
Exception:
List index out of bounds (5)
Callstack:
0000000000450000:00000000004F4A17: FLEngine.dll
0000000000450000:00000000004F4C80: FLEngine.dll
0000000000450000:00000000004F4DAA: FLEngine.dll
0000000000450000:0000000000751242: FLEngine.dll
0000000000450000:000000000088061D: FLEngine.dll
0000000000450000:00000000008803A2: FLEngine.dll
0000000000450000:00000000006FC529: FLEngine.dll
0000000000450000:0000000000B3DCDF: FLEngine.dll
0000000000450000:0000000000B4785A: FLEngine.dll
0000000000450000:0000000001C38B5B: FLEngine.dll
0000000000450000:0000000000CA9A73: FLEngine.dll
0000000000400000:0000000000403985: FL.exe
0000000000400000:0000000000403E5E: FL.exe
0000000000400000:0000000000404D3F: FL.exe
000000007B420000:000000007B4539B1: kernel32.dll
000000007B420000:000000007B453E88: kernel32.dll
000000007B420000:000000007B4539C2: kernel32.dll
0000000000000000:0000000000000000: "
```

Nothing I do seems to remedy this. I've exhausted almost all options like trying to run it on Lutris and even PlayonLinux with similar results.

This is my first time making the switch over to Linux based systems and all the other programs that come with Ubuntu Studio are fantastic, but FL Studio is a must-have for me but I just can't seem to make it work. I've seen some users being able to run it, but I just can't seem to get past this error.

Hope this lovely community can help me out with one, been losing sleep trying to solve this mystery haha.

Cheers, and happy holidays everyone!

Comment: Did you install `winetricks` with `wine`? Did you also run `winetricks` from the console, choose “Select the default wineprefix”, and install the “core” Microsoft fonts? Without these steps, the application will not work.

Answer (score 1):

Patch has been merged into Wine:
https://source.winehq.org/git/wine.git/commit/0a366f7e4a68c9375b54ace5289989bd81b65d22
__
There's a patch ( https://bugs.winehq.org/show_bug.cgi?id=50362 ) but it hasn't been merged into WINE project yet and you have to compile it yourself.
I did so with wine-tkg (fork) and it works!
You can get it here:
https://github.com/kajlando/

Comment: Works with 6.5+ :)

Answer (score 0):

## Wine may need upgraded, but here is a good troubleshooting step

### I. Troubleshoot

This is a good step to solve many `wine` problems, it has worked for me in the past, and at least helps to narrow-down what the problem actually may be:

```sh
sudo apt install winetricks
winetricks
```

- "Select the default wineprefix"
- "Install a font"
- Package: "corefonts"

However, it did not work for me this time.

### II. But wine probably needs upgrading

According to the discussion at the wine homepage "[Wine 5.22 and FL Studio 20 startup error every time](https://forum.winehq.org/viewtopic.php?t=34696)", this seems to be a more extensive problem that may require an upgrade to wine in order to be fixed.